# awk to remove any number

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have some lines in my file like this

```
234 334 ID=as_8;861836..864143;nbOverlappingReads=390
244 254 ID=as_8;861836..864183;nbOverlappingReads=390
```

My desired out put is

```
ID=as_8;nbOverlappingReads=390
ID=as_8;nbOverlappingReads=390
```

I want to remove the numbers in between two semicolons. how to use awk to do this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through sed,

```
sed 's/^\([^;]*\);[^;]*/\1/' file
```

Update:

```
$ sed 's/^[0-9]\+ [0-9]\+ \([^;]*\);[^;]*/\1/' file
ID=as_8;nbOverlappingReads=390
ID=as_8;nbOverlappingReads=390
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[0-9]\+` Matches one or more digits. So `^[0-9]\+ [0-9]\+` would match the starting two numbers.
- `\(...\)`  Called capturing groups.
- `\([^;]*\)` Captures any character but not of `;` zero or more times. Now the 1st group contains the string `ID=as_8`
- `;[^;]*` Matches `;` plus the following characters upto the next `;`
- Now the matched characters are replaced by the characters Which was inside the group index 1.

Comment: could you please explain the regular expression

Comment: super explanation machi  ;)

Comment: machi , Where are you from?

Comment: from Madras, now in paris. If you are interested, we can add in linkedin. tell me your email address or linked link

Answer (score 1):

If the fields in your input are separated by a mixture of whitespace characters (like spaces or tabs) and semicolons, you can specify that with awk:

```
awk -F'[[:space:];]+' '{print $3";"$5}' file
```

Testing it out on your file:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:];]+' '{print $3";"$5}' file
ID=as_8;nbOverlappingReads=390
ID=as_8;nbOverlappingReads=390
```

Comment: could you please look at the edited question. it is also a tab separated file